# Need of script to select the values in the drop down

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to select the category first then have to select the HONDA value in the drop down 
 Below code is to select the category

```
<div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs customtabview" role="tablist">
<div class="tab-content customtabcontainer">
<div id="general" class="tab-pane active">
<form class="form-horizontal form-validation row-border ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-minlength" angular-validator-submit="equipmentsavegeneral()" name="equipmentsave" novalidate="" angular-validator="">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
Category
<span class="mandatory">*</span>
</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<oi-select class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-touched" oi-options="item.id as item.category_name for item in dropdown.categoryname" ng-model="formdata.category" placeholder="Select Category" ng-disabled="formdata.id" ng-change="checksubcategory(formdata.category)">
<div class="select-search">
<ul class="select-search-list">
<li class="select-search-list-item select-search-list-item_input" ng-class="{'select-search-list-item_hide': inputHide}">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" autocomplete="off" ng-model="query" ng-keyup="keyUp($event)" ng-keydown="keyDown($event)" placeholder="Select Category">
</li>
<li class="select-search-list-item select-search-list-item_loader ng-hide" ng-show="showLoader"></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="select-dropdown ng-hide" ng-show="isOpen"></div>
</oi-select>
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" style=" display: none;" data-ng-model="formdata.category" name="selectcat" required="" required-message="'Please select category'" type="text">
</div>
</div>

Below code is to select the value 

    <div class="select-dropdown" ng-show="isOpen">
<ul class="select-dropdown-optgroup ng-scope" ng-if="isOpen" ng-repeat="(group, options) in groups">
<li class="select-dropdown-optgroup-option ng-binding ng-scope ungroup" ng-init="isDisabled = getDisableWhen(option)" ng-repeat="option in options" ng-class="{'active': selectorPosition === groupPos[group] + $index, 'disabled': isDisabled, 'ungroup': !group}" ng-click="isDisabled || addItem(option)" ng-mouseenter="setSelection(groupPos[group] + $index)" ng-bind-html="getDropdownLabel(option)">Bike details</li>
<li class="select-dropdown-optgroup-option ng-binding ng-scope ungroup" ng-init="isDisabled = getDisableWhen(option)" ng-repeat="option in options" ng-class="{'active': selectorPosition === groupPos[group] + $index, 'disabled': isDisabled, 'ungroup': !group}" ng-click="isDisabled || addItem(option)" ng-mouseenter="setSelection(groupPos[group] + $index)" ng-bind-html="getDropdownLabel(option)">Test</li>
<li class="select-dropdown-optgroup-option ng-binding ng-scope ungroup" ng-init="isDisabled = getDisableWhen(option)" ng-repeat="option in options" ng-class="{'active': selectorPosition === groupPos[group] + $index, 'disabled': isDisabled, 'ungroup': !group}" ng-click="isDisabled || addItem(option)" ng-mouseenter="setSelection(groupPos[group] + $index)" ng-bind-html="getDropdownLabel(option)">b</li>
<li class="select-dropdown-optgroup-option ng-binding ng-scope ungroup" ng-init="isDisabled = getDisableWhen(option)" ng-repeat="option in options" ng-class="{'active': selectorPosition === groupPos[group] + $index, 'disabled': isDisabled, 'ungroup': !group}" ng-click="isDisabled || addItem(option)" ng-mouseenter="setSelection(groupPos[group] + $index)" ng-bind-html="getDropdownLabel(option)">LoadOne</li>
<li class="select-dropdown-optgroup-option ng-binding ng-scope ungroup active" ng-init="isDisabled = getDisableWhen(option)" ng-repeat="option in options" ng-class="{'active': selectorPosition === groupPos[group] + $index, 'disabled': isDisabled, 'ungroup': !group}" ng-click="isDisabled || addItem(option)" ng-mouseenter="setSelection(groupPos[group] + $index)" ng-bind-html="getDropdownLabel(option)">HONDA</li>
</ul>
</div>
</oi-select>
```

Need to script to select this i have used xpaths its not working getting element not found

Comment: Can you provide the following: 1. What are your exact steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck? 4. Format your HTML DOM in a readable format.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python to select item based on visible text uc an use below code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

element_obj = element_obj = driver.find_element_by_id('element_id')
select = Select(element_obj)
select.select_by_visible_text('HONDA')
```

And to get list of All available drop down options.

```
element_obj = element_obj = driver.find_element_by_id('element_id')            
select = Select(element_obj)
return [o.text for o in select.options]
```

I am not sure, this is want your requirement is, but solution is based on my understanding of your question